# Export to XLS using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

I want to export more than 200000 rows with 60 Columns from database to the client machine by using browser.  I am using Servlet and POI 3 .8 version jars and below code.

```
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStreamObj = response.getOutputStream();
HSSFWorkbook workBook =  new HSSFWorkbook ();
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + strFileName + ".xls\"");
workBook.write(servletOutputStreamObj);
```

This code is working fine up to 65535 rows.
How to make it for more number of records. (xls/xlsx both format are fine).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"more than 2lack rows"*  What does 2lack mean?

Comment: Are you sending an excel sheet with these many records at a time? You can provide a functionality like pagination so that user can  view the data more comfortably

Comment: its a requirement to export the all data from table to excel....

Comment: @@Andrew s it means 0.2 million and i want up to the capacity of xlsx file support.....

Comment: You need xssf for large spread sheets.(users too will require newer version of office- 2003? Not sure)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [HSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) object which creates an Excel **xls** file which is limited to 65,535 rows.

Instead you should use a [XSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) which creates an Excel **xlsx** file which in turn supports 1,048,576 rows. You should also change your ContentType and the file extension in that case.

And if you run out of memory using XSSFWorkbook try [SXSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf).

Here is the [background](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) to the 3 classes from the Apache POI website.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can take a look at this example for your need.This sample code tries to create excel document upto 100000 records.

[Demonstrates a workaround you can use to generate large workbooks and avoid OutOfMemory exception](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BigGridDemo.java.html)

Comment: Hi @UVM problem again if Data contains < or > symbol its not writing to file after that cell... Can i get any tips....